Fetch data containing the Tags and Business terms using BigQuery with the table/column names
I attached some "Column Tags" and "Business terms" using Dataplex and my goal is to fetch the table/column data with the tags information and business terms, is there a way to do that using Big query

My understanding is that the Dataplex storage for metadata is not queryable from a BigQuery SQL query.  Dataplex provides its own API for performing queries against it that are not SQL based.

I see it @Kolban, from my research, ot looks I can use Google data catalog api to be able to extract this information

Hi @Tayzer, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCPsupport case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.
